# Why do I need a scope.$apply when compiling a directive from another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why do I need a scope.$apply for the scope on the compiled directive to be bound to its template?

Relevant plunker is here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/t3zF1A0BviItmbx9J7ii?p=preview

Comment: your doing angulary things in jquery callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that you need a `scope.$apply` on the `myDirective`, it's that you're using a jQuery / jqLite function (`append`) to add a new directive and Angular has no idea it needs to fire off another digest cycle.

See my change here where I moved the `scope.$apply` to cover the `append` method in your first directive and the result is the same:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fAAHOj?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

there are two things:

1. Events occured inside the angular environment, you do not need to apply these changes as Angular will itself fire a digest cycle and then apply the changes.
2. When you do some changes from outside the environment of Angularjs, then in this case angular will be required to be explicitly told that a change has occured. Hence we write, `$scope.$apply();`
   Even in directive, if it is a change using angular functions there is no need of apply. But in case you used some other library to cause the events, then you need to apply the changes.